# Problems with dependencies of Simperium

Tags: simperium

I am evaluating to move a project to Simperium for synchronization. The project already uses CocoaHTTPServer, ASIHTTPRequest and some other frameworks.

Now Simperium also seems to contain (at least parts of) of these frameworks. Removing the CocoaHTTPServer framework from my projects linking phase, I got undefined symbols linker errors regarding these symbols: HTTPAsyncFileResponse, HTTPFileResponse, HTTPDataResponse, HTTPServer, HTTPDataResponse, HTTPConnection.

Is it possible to fix these linker errors with the current framework version?

Or would it be possible to provide a framework with these frameworks as external, dependant frameworks, so I can use my own versions?

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to [Linker errors building iOS app with Simperium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543277/linker-errors-building-ios-app-with-simperium), which has a suggested workaround while a proper fix is implemented. The proper fix should be ready soon.